# Select only the header with it's pertaining list

Tags: bash, shell-script

i am working on creating a workflow for CICD using jenkins and I have a file that I am grep'ing that is formatted like this:

```
api
qa0=
qa1=
qa3=
qa4=master
qa5=master

feasibility-service
qa0=
qa1=master1
qa3=cloud-config
qa4=
qa5=OTHERBUILD-112.12.3

qa123project-TBH
qa0=master
qa1=
qa3=
qa4=ehhrelease1.2333.1
qa5=
```

So far my code greps the entire file, matches the branch name, and then pulls the QA environment that it needs to be pointed to:

```
if grep "$MAIN_DIR" config && grep $BRANCH_NAME config
then
    echo "Checking if Git Project and Branch Exist, will deploy onto environment specified"
    WORD=$(grep $BRANCH_NAME config)
    INITIAL=${WORD::3}
    echo GITENV=$INITIAL > $PROPS
```

This is giving me issues because if the project being built is for the api and the branch being built if for cloud-config it should fail but instead it picks up the feasibility-service's environment when in fact it should fail.

How can I restrict it to only the list that falls under the branch name (ex api)?

the output for project that matches api should only be:

```
api
qa0=
qa1=
qa3=
qa4=master
qa5=master
```

the output for project that matches qa123project-TBH EXACTLY should only be:

```
qa123project-TBH
qa0=master
qa1=
qa3=
qa4=ehhrelease1.2333.1
qa5=
```

Comment: try, `sed -n "/$BRANCH_NAME/,/^$/p" file`

Comment: This command is exactly what I needed! sed -n "/$MAIN_DIR/,/^$/p" config, how may I create an if statement to match the branch name otherwise exit the command? Ex. sed $MAIN_DIR=api, match the $BRANCH_NAME=master, GITENV=qa4 and GITENV=qa5

Comment: NVM! this did the trick: if sed -n "/$MAIN_DIR/,/^$/p" config | grep $BRANCH_NAME @msp9011 can you post your response as the answer, please?